# Apache Reverse Proxy for SSH Tunnel

Tags: ssh, apache-2.4, apache2, ssh-tunnel

I want to set up an Apache reverse proxy for my Home-Assistant(hass) instance running in my local network.

I tunnelled the traffic of the local hass instance to a remote server with `ssh -N proxy@example.com -R 8123:localhost:8123`.

Now I tried to set up a plain reverse proxy in Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName hass.example.com

    SSLEngine On

    # If you manage SSL certificates by yourself, these paths will differ.
    SSLCertificateFile fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile privkey.pem

    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLProxyProtocol +TLSv1.2 +TLSv1.3
    SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyVia On
    RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
    
            
    # Proxy all traffic to hass
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8123/ nocanon
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/hass.example.com-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/hass.example.com-access.log combined
    <IfModule security2_module>
        SecRuleEngine off
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName hass.example.com

    Redirect permanent / "https://hass.example.com"

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/hass.example.com-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/hass.example.com-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Sadly if I try to open `hass.example.com`, the browser responds with `400: Bad Request`.

Comment: you want guacamole, apache cant handle ssh by itself

Comment: Is your `hass` configured to run at domain name `hass.example.com`?

Comment: @Tero Kilkanen No. It's just an vanilla docker container listening on localhost.

Comment: @djdomi I don't use SSH with Apache. I just use the (via SSH) local port `8123` and just want to proxy it.

Comment: The `hass` should have configuration for its root domain name. You need to check that.

Comment: I actually don't get why this should be a problem because it's a transperent proxy. The proxy only requests `localhost:8123`. I should add: If I do something along the lines of `ssh -L 8123:localhost:8123 -N proxy@example.com` I can easily access `localhost:8123` on the machine I executed the command. So the SSH tunnel itself is working.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I also tried to open the port 8123 to the public and I'm able to access my hass instance via example.com:8123 but that's not really what I want, since I want to route my traffic through the Apache proxy. I don't think the root domain name is in any way configurable and doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all boils down to [Home-Assistant blocking revers-proxy](https://www.home-assistant.io/integrations/http#reverse-proxies) attempts and that you have to [proxy websocket requests as well](https://community.home-assistant.io/t/serving-home-assistant-via-apache-reverse-proxy/240743).

Adjusted hass-config (`config/configuration.yaml`):

```yaml
http:
  use_x_forwarded_for: true
  trusted_proxies:
  - ::1
  - 127.0.0.1
  ip_ban_enabled: true
  login_attempts_threshold: 5
```

Apache config:

```xml
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName hass.example.com

    SSLEngine On

    # If you manage SSL certificates by yourself, these paths will differ.
    SSLCertificateFile fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile privkey.pem

    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLProxyProtocol +TLSv1.2 +TLSv1.3
    SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyVia On
    RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
    
            
    # Proxy all traffic to hass
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket
    RewriteRule /(.*) ws://localhost:8123/$1 [P]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket
    RewriteRule /(.*) http://localhost:8123/$1 [P]
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8123


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/hass.example.com-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/hass.example.com-access.log combined
    <IfModule security2_module>
        SecRuleEngine off
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName hass.example.com

    Redirect permanent / "https://hass.example.com"

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/hass.example.com-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/hass.example.com-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```